# How do i use Pygame get_size()?

Tags: python, pygame

I've been coding a DVD screen saver in python but i'm having trouble getting the window size from pygame. I've used Info(), get_size(), get_width() and get_height(), none of which change when i resize the window.

I'm coding this in python 3.5.3, i tried reinstalling pygame and then i tried switching to python 3.6 and installing pygame for that but nothing has worked.

```
import pygame as p, random as r, time as t, sys

width, height = 640, 480 #Initial screen width & height
x, y, vel = 0, 0, [1, 1] #Makes coordinates and velocity
DVD = p.image.load('sprites\\w.png') #Loads a sprite
DVDRECT = DVD.get_rect() #Makes object for the sprites to be loaded onto
screen = p.display.set_mode((width, height),p.RESIZABLE) #Sets screen to resizable mode
p.display.set_caption('DVD')#Sets executable capton
p.init() #Initialize Pygame

x, y = r.randint(200, 400), r.randint(200, 400) #sets the start location

#Loads in sprites
wht = p.image.load('sprites\\w.png')
blu = p.image.load('sprites\\b.png')
pnk = p.image.load('sprites\\p2.png')
pur = p.image.load('sprites\\p.png')
grn = p.image.load('sprites\\g.png')
org = p.image.load('sprites\\o.png')
ylw = p.image.load('sprites\\y.png')
p.display.set_icon(wht)

def new_color():
    """
    Function for getting random colors
    """
    return r.choice([wht, blu, pnk, pur, grn, org, ylw])

while True:
    print(screen.get_size())
    for event in p.event.get():
        if event.type == p.QUIT:
            p.quit()
            sys.exit()
    #Makes new coordinates:
    x += vel[0]
    y += vel[1]

    #Checks if logo hits a wall
    if x >= width-29:
        vel[0] = -vel[0] #Makes logo 'bounce' off wall
        DVD = new_color() #Sets a new color to the logo
        p.display.set_icon(DVD)

    if x <= 29:
        vel[0] = -vel[0]
        DVD = new_color()
        p.display.set_icon(DVD)

    if y >= height-19:
        vel[1] = -vel[1]
        DVD = new_color()
        p.display.set_icon(DVD)

    if y <= 19:
        vel[1] = -vel[1]
        DVD = new_color()
        p.display.set_icon(DVD)

    DVDRECT.center = (x, y) #moves the logo
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0)) #sets background to black
    screen.blit(DVD, DVDRECT) #Updates logo
    p.display.flip() #flips screen
    t.sleep(1.0/80.0) #waits certian time between frames
```

I was expecting the output of print(screen.get_size()) to change when i resized the window, but the tuple it shows remains (640, 480) no matter what i do to the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I had to use the event handler to get when the user resizes the screen, how big they made it then redefine the width and height by redefining the screen variable

```
    if event.type == p.VIDEORESIZE:
        scrsize = event.size
        screen = p.display.set_mode(scrsize, p.RESIZABLE)
        width, height = scrsize[0], scrsize[1]
        if DVDRECT.center[0] >= width-29:
            y = DVDRECT.center[1]
            x = width-30
            DVDRECT.center = (x, y)
        if DVDRECT.center[1] >= height-19:
            y = height-20
            DVDRECT.center = (x, y)
        corners = [(width-29, height-19), (29, 19), (width-29, 19), (29, height-19)]
```

From here the code works fine.